# Way to wait on return from Dialogue PreferenceActivity before continuing through code

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

For some reason this seems like a simple problem I am having a hard time with, too much time staring at the computer probably. I have some code where I can click on text to open a menu (in the form of a Dialogue PreferenceActivity) that allows me to edit whether a timer is used and if so how long the timer lasts. The problem I encounter is that when I click on the box, it continues through the code in my main activity thread and performs the actions before I have a chance to change the settings in the edit menu.

```
case R.id.main_timer:
    startActivity(new Intent(this, EditSettingsView.class));
    // NEED TO WAIT HERE FOR OVERLYING INTENT TO CLOSE

    boolean editedSettingTimerOn = editedSetting.getBoolean("edit_timer_active", true);
    if(editedSettingTimrOn == true){
        startTimer(editedSetting.getLong("edit_timer_val", 180000);
    }
    break;
```

I need to wait for the Activity EditSettingView.class to finish before I get the boolean, so that I get the newly selected boolean as opposed to the value that it is set to when the activity opens. Is there a way to implement onPause() to create a break in the code there and then return when the overlying EditSettingView PreferenceActivity is closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to implement onPause() to create a break in the code there and then return when the overlying EditSettingView PreferenceActivity is closed?

No. Android does not offer a blocking UI model.

You can implement [an `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html), attach it to your `SharedPreferences`, and move your code after the comment to the `onSharedPreferenceChanged()` method of the `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`, when you detect that the `edit_timer_active` preference has changed.

Or, put your `edit_timer_active`-checking code in `onResume()` of this activity.

Comment: This also actually looks like it will work. I will have to take a look at this.

Comment: Moved the code to onResume, works like a charm. Don't know why I didn't think of it but thank you for the help. Though I feel OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener and startActivityForResult(), as majormajors answered with, are cleaner it still got the job done by just doing a code shift. Check for you.

Answer (score 0):

Android's way of handling this would be to use `startActivityForResult()`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities

Your `EditSettingView` activity would then call `setResult(RESULT_OK)` before it finishes and then the original activity's `onActivityResult()` will be called.

Comment: This looks like the way to go, I am currently working on trying to implement it. Thank you for the response.

Comment: I will try to post in my edited code, but as of now I am getting a null error (Failure delivering result).